# How to separate labels into columns in the enumerate environment?

Tags: enumerate, labels, multicolumn

How to separate labels into columns in the enumerate environment? The desired effect is like below:
[image]

For example, if there are for items, the desired effect is for them to spread out evenly in one line (suppose each item is brief enough to be stuffed into the columns), just like what it would appear in the `multicolumn` function. I wonder whether it can be done in the `enumerate` environment since this can save me a lot of typesetting while turning exam problems into latex.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You can use ```https://github.com/xkwxdyy/xchoices```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without details, it's hard to predict what a use case might be here. If it's a single line, this can be done simply by using the `tabular` environment with just one row.

However, you may also expect this to be:

- extended to multiple lines
- each item having a unique label,
- each row having 4 columns, and
- labels to be automatically countered.

Then, have a look at [tasks](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tasks)

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\newcommand\mm[1]{\ensuremath{\displaystyle #1}}

\begin{document}
\noindent \kant[1][1]

\begin{tasks}[label=\Alph*.,label-width=1em,column-sep=1em,item-format=\mm](4)
  \task 2
  \task \frac{1}{2}
  \task -\frac{1}{2}
  \task =2
\end{tasks}

\noindent \kant[1][2]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it very simply with the `inline` option of enumitem and the `enumerate*` environment:

```
        \documentclass{article}
        \usepackage{amsmath}
        \usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

        \begin{document}

        \begin{enumerate*}[label=\Alph*. , itemjoin=\hskip 6em]
          \item $2$ \item $\dfrac{1}{2}$ \item $-\dfrac{1}{2}$ \item $-2$
        \end{enumerate*}

        \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But I notice that the `itemjoin` parameter needs to be adjusted manually. Although some slight adjustments do help solve the problem, but is there method which can automatically decide how much should the space be (I haven't learnt much abouth this kind of syntax)? A further question is that, when the items do not have the same horizontal length, the space between the two adjacent items is constant; but what if the desired effect is for Each item to be kind of stuffed into a equal box? Nevertheless, thanks for your answer!

Comment: @erpxyr2001: to have each item contents placed in an equal box, you can use the `eqparbox` package.